# Structuring Unstructured data with mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a log file, A near snapshot is given below:

```
<Dec 12, 2013 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <java.rmi.RemoteException>
<Dec 13, 2013 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <Io exception>
<Dec 14, 2013 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <garbage data
garbage data
garbade data
Io exception
>
<jan 01, 2014 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <garbage data
garbage data java.rmi.RemoteException
>
```

I am trying to built an analysis on top of it.

What I want to do:

I want to get the count of Exception per year

```
for Example: from above sample data my output should be

    java.rmi.RemoteException 2013 1
    Io exception             2013 2
    java.rmi.RemoteException 2014 1
```

What is my problem:

```
1.You see hadoop processes line by line of a text file, so it considers Io exception as
 a part of line 6 whereas it should be a part of line 3 (that is continued till line 7).

2. I can't use N line input formatter because ther's no fixed pattern of lines.
```

What is the pattern and what I want:

```
The only pattern I see is that a line starts with a "<" and ends with a ">". In the 
above example line 3 doesn't end with ">" hence I want the compiler to consider all the 
data in the same line until it fetches a ">".
```

The sample data how I want my compiler to see is :

```
<Dec 12, 2013 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <java.rmi.RemoteException>
<Dec 13, 2013 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <Io exception>
<Dec 14, 2013 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <garbage data garbage data garbade data Io exception>
<jan 01, 2014 2:46:24 AM CST> <Error> <garbage data garbage data java.rmi.RemoteException>
```

I will be glad If anybody could share a piece of code or idea to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement your InputFormat & RecordReader. What you really need is an adaptation of StreamInputFormat. This is present in hadoop-streaming project.

For our usage which is a multi line XML we use hadoop-straeming to read from start tag to end tag which we define. You can check the source and adapt it for your requirements.